# MSFT All-in-one keyboard touchpad not working

Tags: kubuntu, touchpad, 20.10, synaptics, libinput

I'm trying to use an external Microsoft All-in-one keyboard on a fresh install of my distro.
The keyboard itself works out of the box, even the keyboard shortcuts.
Unfortunately, the integrated touchpad seems to be detected but is not usable at all.

**General informations:**

```
OS: Kubuntu 20.10 x86_64
Kernel: 5.8.0-50-generic
```

I've installed all the necessary (?) packages such as `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`

**Xinput:**

```
xinput --list
```

```
> ⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)] ⎜   
>↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4   [slave  pointer  (2)] ⎜   
>↳ MSI MSI Clutch GM40 GAMING Mouse         id=21   [slave  pointer  (2)] ⎜   
>↳ MSI MSI Clutch GM40 GAMING Mouse Consumer Control id=23   [slave  pointer  (2)] ⎜   
>↳ Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0 Consumer Control       id=13   [slave pointer  (2)]    
>↳ Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0 Consumer Control       id=15   [slave  pointer (2)] 
>↳ Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0 Mouse  id=20   [slave  pointer  (2)]
>↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=17   [slave pointer  (2)]
```

I think the one i'm interested in is the id=20

```
xinput list-props 20
```

```
Device 'Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0 Mouse':
        Device Enabled (174):   1
        Coordinate Transformation Matrix (176): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (312):       0
        libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (313):       0
        libinput Scroll Methods Available (314):        0, 0, 1
        libinput Scroll Method Enabled (315):   0, 0, 0
        libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (316):   0, 0, 0
        libinput Button Scrolling Button (317): 2
        libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (318): 2
        libinput Button Scrolling Button Lock Enabled (319):    0
        libinput Button Scrolling Button Lock Enabled Default (320):    0
        libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (321):        0
        libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (322):        0
        libinput Accel Speed (323):     0.000000
        libinput Accel Speed Default (324):     0.000000
        libinput Accel Profiles Available (325):        1, 1
        libinput Accel Profile Enabled (326):   1, 0
        libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (327):   1, 0
        libinput Left Handed Enabled (328):     0
        libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (329):     0
        libinput Send Events Modes Available (297):     1, 0
        libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (298):        0, 0
        libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (299):        0, 0
        Device Node (300):      "/dev/input/event9"
        Device Product ID (301):        1118, 2048
        libinput Drag Lock Buttons (330):       <no items>
        libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (331):       1
```

The device looks like it's enabled.
I've tried to disable and renable it, no change.

**Dmesg:**

Interesting part of dmesg when plugged it in and out

```
[ 1252.043755] usb 1-4: USB disconnect, device number 8
[ 1261.085542] usb 1-4: new full-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[ 1261.239498] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=0800, bcdDevice= 9.34
[ 1261.239503] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 1261.239506] usb 1-4: Product: Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0
[ 1261.239509] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Microsoft
[ 1261.243434] input: Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:045E:0800.000A/input/input33
[ 1261.301883] hid-generic 0003:045E:0800.000A: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input0
[ 1261.308273] input: Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0 Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.1/0003:045E:0800.000B/input/input34
[ 1261.308518] input: Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0 Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.1/0003:045E:0800.000B/input/input35
[ 1261.308631] hid-generic 0003:045E:0800.000B: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input1
[ 1261.315364] input: Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0 Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.2/0003:045E:0800.000C/input/input36
[ 1261.373750] input: Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0 System Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.2/0003:045E:0800.000C/input/input38
[ 1261.373925] hid-generic 0003:045E:0800.000C: input,hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Device [Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input2
```

**Devices:**

```
cat /proc/bus/input/devices
```

```
I: Bus=0003 Vendor=045e Product=0800 Version=0111
N: Name="Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:045E:0800.000A/input/input33
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event8 leds 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=1000000000007 ff800000000007ff febeffdff3cfffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=045e Product=0800 Version=0111
N: Name="Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0 Mouse"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input1
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.1/0003:045E:0800.000B/input/input34
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event9 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=17
B: KEY=1f0000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=1943
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=045e Product=0800 Version=0111
N: Name="Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0 Consumer Control"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input1
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.1/0003:045E:0800.000B/input/input35
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event10 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=5
B: REL=1040

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=045e Product=0800 Version=0111
N: Name="Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0 Consumer Control"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input2
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.2/0003:045E:0800.000C/input/input36
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event11 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=10001f
B: KEY=3f000301ff 0 0 483ffff17aff32d bfd4444600000000 1 130ff38b17c007 ffff7bfad9415fff ffbeffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: REL=1040
B: ABS=100000000
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=045e Product=0800 Version=0111
N: Name="Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0 System Control"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input2
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.2/0003:045E:0800.000C/input/input38
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event12 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=40000001000000 1200000000 0 800000000 40000010cc00 10168000000000 0
B: ABS=10000000000
B: MSC=10
```

**Xorg:**

And finally a Xorg.log available at: https://pastebin.com/9mDxN0cn (interesting part at the end, I believe)

```
2573.773] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: touchpad found
[  2574.144] (II) libinput: Microsoft MicrosoftÂ® Nano Transceiver v2.0 Mouse: SetProperty on 328 called but device is disabled.
This driver cannot change properties on a disabled device
```

I've also tried to run evtest but nothing was written in the log file.

---

I've seen a few posts and bug reports on launchpad about this issue (or similar), but none of the given solutions worked for me.
The touchpad even appears in Kubuntu's GUI in Touchpad settings (as Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0 Mouse). External mouse and integrated laptop's touchpad work just fine.

I couldnt find the exact model of the keyboard, but it looks like it's the **N9Z-00001** keyboard.

So why does the external touchpad (mouse) seems like it's being detected but is not working at all ?
I will provide some more informations if needed, thank you !

Comment: Good chance Microsoft needs to make an exact driver for this keyboard that works with Ubuntu.

Comment: The touchpad being detected as a mouse is a typical symptom of a lack of the touchpad driver. Here's a [list of similar kernel bugzilla reports](https://bit.ly/3slp4mk), both solved and not *(sry, had to shorten the link because even alone it is 390 characters too long for the comment box)*. What you can do here is [to test latest mainline kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade) to see if it got driver, then if not, report a bug to launchpad and kernel bugzilla.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same device and when I installed Kubuntu 20.04 (kernel 5.1.1.0-27 generic) touchpad has worked immediately.